# What is the current status of India's RLV craft?

Tags: space-shuttle, isro

What is their underlying technology, and is it going to be cheaper like their Mars orbital mission?

Comment: eltonjain, welcome to Space Exploration! You may want to check out our Help resources in the toolbar above to learn a little more about how this community works. We prefer more specific questions here.

Comment: Yes or no. Just that, but as of now they have tested the miniature shuttle design, heat sheild (carbon cone), guidance system and recently mini scramjet ramjet rocket hybrid on sounding rocket. It started burn 55sec in flight it was success. It will take 2 decade atleast.